# classic ASP error '80020009' Exception occurred

Tags: exception, asp-classic

On line 5 of the code to a site I am fixing, I get an exception error from classic ASP. The ** line below is line 5. It looks like this function is used on other pages in the site, although I'm not quite sure why.  I've tried just removing the code, but since it's used other places, it must be important, so maybe I shouldn't try removing it....

```
Private Function AE(myString)
**If myString <> "" then** 
AE = Replace(myString,"`","'")
End If
End Function
```

Here is an example of where `AE` is used: `response.write AE(rs("ArticleTitle"))`

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This probably means that the field in the database is Null. You could add this line before the problematic line:

```
If isNull( myString ) Then Exit Function
```

In case that doesn't work, you could also try changing the problematic line into this:

```
If "" & myString <> "" Then
```

Comment: Awesome! The `isNull` check worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: I had the same error and it turned out the database call had returned EOF and I had forgotton to check for this.

Answer (score 1):

This error also comes up if you try to access a record in a recordset which has no records (ie if you forgot to check for eof before accessing the fields).

Answer (score 0):

check before replace, does ` does this exist in string by

```
if instr(mystring, "`") then
'your code
else
'your code
end if
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the ASCII character code instead of a single quote:

```
AE = Replace(myString,"`",chr(39))
```